# Stop Autohotkey hotstring last symbol trigger

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use hotstrings but I have problems with the 'Z' option.

**This is my code:**

```
d::
    Return

:?*CZB0:dw::
    Send, asdf
    Return
```

**Explanation:**

I'm trying to define a hotstring 'dw'. I don't want to see the 'd', so I redefine it to just Return, and I disable backspacing by the 'B0' option. The problem is that although I'm using the 'Z' option, the 'w' still appears.

**Example:**

I send 'd' -> Nothing appears in the text field

I send 'w' -> 'wasdf' appears in the text field

I want to see only 'asdf'. Isn't this what the 'Z' option is for? How can I achieve that?

**P.S.** I can not redefine the 'w' to just Return - I'm using it for something else.

The actual code is [here](https://github.com/lubokkanev/vim-everywhere). And [this](https://github.com/lubokkanev/vim-everywhere/blob/master/src/shortcuts/vim/copy-paste-cut.ahk) is the file I'm asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Cheap, but why don't you just backspace over the `w`?:

**This is my modification:**

```
d::
    Return

:?*CZB0:dw::
    Send, {bs}asdf
    Return
```

Hth,

Comment: I'm giving a simple example, but in my actual case, the 'w' is defined to do something complex and I can't undo it. Thanks for the answer though.